# Fourier series using other bases?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

The theory of Fourier series, representing a reasonable function by an infinite sum of exponential functions, is very well-developed. In addition to basic functional-analytic results there are things like Carleson's theorem, Dirichlet's theorem, and Fejer's theorem, which are much more subtle. Basic functional analysis books, like Kreyszig's, deal with the theory of "Fourier" series in Hilbert spaces more generally, and mention that there are other total orthonormal bases (such as the Legendre polynomials), but develop only results independent of the basis. Stein and Shakarchi's book, the only other one I've looked in, also only mentions mean-square convergence of Legendre series. Are there theories total orthonormal bases (of real or complex functions) other than the exponential one that are at least somewhat as well-developed as the theory of Fourier series? Are there other bases that are somehow just as good at representing reasonable functions in the $L^p$ norm **and** pointwise?

Answer (score 1):

Wavelets are another class of orthonormal basis functions onto which a given function can be decomposed (See [Wavelets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet)).  Unlike the exponential, they are parameterized by width and location, so they can be more effective at analyzing transient behavior.